# Sharepoint 2010 workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a requirement to set up a workflow from an outlook email. The email is sent out each time a new employee joins the organization and it contains their name, employeeid, Job Ref, Start date, Department, email address etc.

The requirement is:

1. The workflow should be able to send an email to the new staff attaching a link to one of the forms to complete.
2. The workflow should also be able to calculate the number of days it took the user to complete the form. If it's more than 3 days, a reminder email should be sent to the user repeatedly until he/she completes the form.

Please I need help on how to go about it. I tried to create a document library but there is no option for an email format.

Help please!!

Comment: I'm not sure how you'd provide the subsequent emails based on time, so will not try to answer that. The initial email is setup within the workflow. All of the information which you have in your List will be fed into the workflow email. Create your workflow, add a step to "send an email", edit the email with the proper fields, set the workflow initiate on item entry, save the workflow, then publish. Every time someone puts in a new item, an email will be sent out.